# Definability in $\Bbb N$ + $\Bbb Z$

Tags: logic, order-theory

Which elements are definable in $\Bbb N$ + $\Bbb Z$? Where an element, a,  is definable if there exists a formula such that $\forall x(\phi(x) \rightarrow x = a) $.

I have that all elements of $\Bbb N$ are definable, since 0 is definable as the unique minimal element, and the next greatest is definable using the successor function.

I want to say that no element of $\Bbb Z$ is definable, but I'm not sure exactly why not?

Comment: What is your language? Successor only? The order relation?

Comment: The claim "no element of $\mathbb Z$ is definable" cannot be true, if all elements of $\mathbb N$ are definable. You proably mean the negative integers.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Since the question is tagged order-theory, I would assume the language has just the order relation. (But successor is first-order definable from that, of course).

Comment: @Peter: The question makes sense if we take it to be "the linear order that consists of _one copy of_ $\mathbb N$ to the left of _one copy of_ $\mathbb Z$". Such constructions are not unusual for defining linear order types.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, but the question talks about successor specifically - and order is not definable from successor . . . (Of course, the answer doesn't actually depend on whether you have the whole ordering or just the successor operation, but it's still worth pointing out.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Good point. Though, in this particular case, order doesn't actually confer any additional definitional power.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  The language is the linear order relation. (I fixed my error re. referencing least rather than unique minimal element). Successor function is misleading as well, I used it as shorthand for the idea that 1 is defined as the unique element with just one element below it, and in general if k is defined by the formula $\theta (k)$ for any element k, then k+1 is the least thing that is bigger than the unique x for which $\theta (x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument that every element of the $\mathbb N$ part is definable looks valid.

In order to prove that no element of the $\mathbb Z$ part is definable, find an order automorphism that leaves no element of the $\mathbb Z$ part fixed. A definable element is necessarily fixed by every automorphism.

Comment: Thanks! Could the relevant automorphism just be f: $\Bbb N + \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb N + \Bbb Z$ s/t f( x : x$\in \Bbb Z) \rightarrow (x+2)$?

Comment: @J.R.CD: Yes, that seems to work fine (though strictly speaking you should define what it does on the $\mathbb N$ part too).

Comment: Okay, thanks so much!